# MonoDevelop key binding for Quick Fix and Show fixes not working

Tags: monodevelop

I have OSX 10.8.2 and MonoDevelop 3.0.4.7 install yet I can't get those darn quick-fix key binding working. `Quick fix...` is assigned to `[Alt]+[Return]` and `Show fixes` is `[Cmd]+[Ctrl]+[.]`. But when I press those nothing happens at all. The simplest use-case of those for me creating stubs and adding some imports.

I come from the Visual Studio world so maybe there are some differences in this behaviour? Any clues how to get those shortcuts working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have source analysis turned on for these things to work, however there are some issues with the keybindings but Alt+Return should work out of the box with quick fix.

But remember source analysis turned on under Preferences.

Comment: Note that source analysis slows MD down a *lot* unless you manually launch MD using the SGen garbage collector, which has to be done from a terminal: `mono --gc=sgen /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.exe`

Comment: Fortunately, it's currently looking like MD 4.0 will use SGen by default. Also, some of the Quick Fixes will be available even when Source Analysis is disabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not realise that I needed to enable Source Analysis. Finally is is somewhat closer to my usual VS experience :)